# Property tag in JNLP-file

Tags: java, security, digital-signature, jnlp, java-web-start

My Java Web Start application have own digital signature. All jar-files are signed, but my application still show security warning dialog "Part of the application is missing a digital signature. Only run if you trust the origin of the application". I have found that warning is caused if i use property tag in jnlp-file. Without property tags everything works perfectly. Is there alternative ways to pass properties? (different tags or something)

In JNLP-file, i have defined some properties like:

```
<property name="loginconfig" value="//loginconfigpath" />
<property name="iconmap" value="//iconmappath" />
```

etc..

Comment: Have you signed all the jars referenced in your jnlp?

Comment: Yes. Warning is caused only if i use property tag in jnlp-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Java Network Launch Protocol (JNLP) Support: Command Line Arguments](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-142562.html#COMMAND_LINE_ARGS)..

> ### Command Line Arguments
>
> The JNLP file syntax supports multiple mechanisms for passing command line arguments to the JVM. The `java-vm-args` attribute of the `<java>` tag may be used, the `max-heap-size` attribute of the same tag may cause implicit specification of an `-Xmx argument`, or a system property may be specified with the `<property>` tag.
>
> The new Java Plug-In supports specification of JVM command-line arguments on a per-applet basis, so all of these features of the JNLP file format are supported, with some rules and restrictions.
>
> A set of "secure" JVM command-line arguments and system properties is defined in the JNLP File Syntax section of the Java Web Start Developers' Guide. In the new Java Plug-In, by default, only these secure command-line arguments may be specified on a per-applet basis.
>
> Non-secure command-line arguments may only be specified on a per-applet basis if:
>
> - the applet is launched via a JNLP file, and
> - the command-line arguments are specified in the JNLP file, and
> - the applet's **JNLP file is signed.**

I suspect they have extended that to include *any* JNLP file (as opposed to just applets), and that this use of properties has triggered that error you are seeing.